# Command Line Tools expired, ReSharper 8 EAP

Tags: .net, windows-8, command-line, .net-4.0, resharper

I was using InspectCode for 4 or 5 days but today when I tried to run it gave me an error:

> JetBrains InspectCode for .NETRunning in 64-bit mode,  .NET runtime
>   4.0.30319.18033 under Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0 This pre-release build of JetBrains JetBrains InspectCode for .NET Build 8.0.0.0 has
>   expired.Please update to a newer version:
>   http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+8+EAP
>   Failed to start JetBrains InspectCode for .NET.

I was also using version version 8.0.0.33 (it seems latest for CMD Tools), and checked that there isn't other new version.

Comment: You should probably ask this on the ReSharper EAP forum: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/resharper/resharper_eap